# How to show MediaElementJS audio playlist to be shown on top of the controls?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, mediaelement.js

I have a mediaelementjs audio player in the footer as shown in this image below.

My questions are posted in the image above.

I want my audio player to look like this joomla audio player below (I am doing my project in Asp.Net MVC c#). Joomla player is in php,I could not use it my project.The playlist is shown to top of control bar when toggled. Mine toggles down below the control bar.

[Joomla Sticky Full Width Audio](http://meetcms.com/module-html5-audioplayer#loginModal)

[image]

I used MediaElementJS audio, I want playlist toggle up above the control bar, not down.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change the scrollbar design colors and color by using changing css of -webkit-scrollbar.

[-webkit-scrollbar css](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customize-the-browsers-scrollbar-with-css)

Then,for making the playlist appear on top of control bar rather than bottom of it,all I had to change is playlistposition property of the mediaelementJS to 'top'.

```
              $(function () {
                $('#mejsAudio').mediaelementplayer({
                    loop: true,
                    shuffle: true,
                    playlist: true,
                    audioHeight: 30,
                    audioWidth:  "100%",
                    playlistposition: 'top',
                    audioVolume: 'vertical',
                    features: ['playlistfeature', 'prevtrack', 'playpause', 'nexttrack', 'loop', 'shuffle', 'playlist', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume']
                      });

            });
```